# Golang Fprint* what does the f stand for

Tags: go

The `fmt` package has some functions for string formatting.
`Sprint*` I am pretty sure stands for string print.
`Print*` writes to STDOUT
What does the `F` stand for with the `Fprint*` functions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "f" stands for "file" - it's a C/Unix-ism. Of course `Fprint` can write to arbitrary `Writer`s, but in the Unix world file is a pretty generic concept and can refer to pretty much anything from "normal" files to socket (streams) or data generated by programs (before any downvotes - yes, I know I'm a bit oversimplifying things, but the question wasn't about the Unix concept of a file so...)

The fmt function names are similar to the C names to ease C programmers already familiar with them in.